# loop or each? or other jQuery solution?

Tags: jquery

How can I simplify the code below into just one element? Hoe can I avoid repetition for each function?

```js
$('#pane-A .accordion.tabs').each(function() {
  if ($(this).length > 3)
    return;
  $('#pane-A .accordion.tabs:gt(2)').hide();
});

$('#pane-B .accordion.tabs').each(function() {
  if ($(this).length > 3)
    return;
  $('#pane-B .accordion.tabs:gt(2)').hide();
});

$('#pane-C .accordion.tabs').each(function() {
  if ($(this).length > 3)
    return;
  $('#pane-C .accordion.tabs:gt(2)').hide();
});

$('#pane-D .accordion.tabs').each(function() {
  if ($(this).length > 3)
    return;
  $('#pane-D .accordion.tabs:gt(2)').hide();
});

$('#pane-E .accordion.tabs').each(function() {
  if ($(this).length > 3)
    return;
  $('#pane-E .accordion.tabs:gt(2)').hide();
});
```

Comment: Just use a a comma in your selector to select all ids. Make use of 'this' to select to correct id

Comment: Can you post your (relevant) HTML? While it's clear in your jQuery what you're doing, I feel there is almost certainly an easier way to achieve this functionality (possibly with CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a common class on all the `#pane-X` elements. Then you can loop through them in a single `each()` statement using `find()` to get the related elements to hide.

Also note that the `if` statement is largely redundant, as jQuery functions are tolerant of missing elements, also that the `:gt()` selector is deprecated. Use `slice()` instead.

With that said, the code can be reduced to just the following for all instances:

```js
$('.pane').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.accordion.tabs').slice(3).hide();
});
```

```css
.pane { margin: 10px 0; } /* just for demo purposes */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pane" id="pane-A">
  Pane A
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 4</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 5</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 6</div>
</div>
<div class="pane" id="pane-B">
  Pane B
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 2</div>
</div>
<div class="pane" id="pane-C">
  Pane C
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 4</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 5</div>
  <div class="accordion tabs">Tab 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work.

```
    $('#pane-A, #pane-B, #pane-C, #pane-D, #pane-E').each(function() {
        let tabs = $('.accordion.tabs', this);
        if (tabs.length > 3) return;
        $('.accordion.tabs:gt(2)', this).hide();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why this anwser gets downvoted. Would use the same approach: +1. EDIT: All accordion tabs are hidden now vs only the one with the correct tab

Comment: @Wimanicesir I don't agree, this `$('.accordion.tabs:gt(2)').hide();` would not work as it should, because it's not targeting the specific `.accordion.tabs` inside the `#pane-(A-E)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Indeed I just realized it as well (see edit)

Comment: This answer went to the trouble of having a scoped `tabs` variable and then threw that away on the last line and updated all `.accordion.tabs` in the entire page

Comment: My bad on this one. Glad Rory's answer works for you!

Comment: `if (tabs.length > 3) return;` probably should have been `if (tabs.length <= 3) return;`